# FreeBSD permissions/ACL issue?

Tags: freebsd, chmod, acl

I'm a bit green with permissions/ACLs on FreeBSD 11, but this is puzzling me.

```
root@svr: # su
root@svr: # id
uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel)
root@svr: ls -lt
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 root  wheel  505 Aug  4 01:32 test.sh
root@svr: getfacl test.sh
# file: test.sh
# owner: root
# group: wheel
        owner@:rwxpDdaARWcCos:------I:allow
        group@:rwxpDdaARWcCos:------I:allow
     everyone@:r-x---a-R-c---:------I:allow
root@svr: chmod 755 test.sh
chmod: test.sh: Operation not permitted
```

I'm logged in as root, classic permissions and acls both say I own the file and have the rights needed (at least I hope they say that?), chflags isn't set (at least I haven't done it), so what am I missing?

Are classic permissions actually locked out if ACLs are in use, and if so, what is the ACL equivalent for that command?

Comment: You can try `chmod -N test.sh` to remove the acl.

Comment: What filesystem type is the file on? What is the output of `ls -lo test.sh`?

Comment: `chmod -N test.sh` won't work in FreeBSD. To remove the ACL use `setfacl -k test.sh`. Refer to [setfacl(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setfacl)